# Qt - Unexpected GDB Exit

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qt-creator

I am trying to develop an application that creates an image and fills it with color pixels using bilinear interpolation and then displays it. My code so far is the following:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/stat.h>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat image;
    image.create( 500, 500, CV_8UC3);
    //upper left corner
    Vec3b ul( 255, 0, 0 );
    //upper right corner
    Vec3b ur( 0, 255, 0 );
    //bottom left corner
    Vec3b bl( 0, 0, 255 );
    //bottom right corner
    Vec3b br( 255, 0, 255 );

    //for(int y=0;y<image.rows; y++)
        //for(int x=0;x<image.cols;x++)

    // call function to add noise

    namedWindow("Colored Pixels");
    imshow("Colored Pixels", image);

    // shows image for 5 seconds
    waitKey(10000);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run my program in debug mode I get the following two pop up windows:

```
Unexpected GDB Exit 
The gdb process exited unexpectedly (code 0)
```

and

```
Executable Failed
During startup program exited with code 0xc0000138
```

my debugger log screen shows the following:

```
sStarting debugger 'GdbEngine' for ABI 'x86-windows-msys-pe-32bit'...
dStart parameters: 'pixelGradient' mode: 1
dABI: x86-windows-msys-pe-32bit
dExecutable: C:\Users\encore\Desktop\Lectures\Year 3\QtCreator\pixelGradient-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MinGW__Qt_SDK__Debug\debug\pixelGradient.exe  [terminal]
dDirectory: C:\Users\encore\Desktop\Lectures\Year 3\QtCreator\pixelGradient-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MinGW__Qt_SDK__Debug
dDebugger: C:\QtSDK\pythongdb\python_2.7based\gdb-i686-pc-mingw32.exe
dProject: C:\Users\encore\Desktop\Lectures\Year 3\QtCreator\pixelGradient (built: C:\Users\encore\Desktop\Lectures\Year 3\QtCreator\pixelGradient-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MinGW__Qt_SDK__Debug)
dQt: C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw
dQML server: 127.0.0.1:3768
dSysroot: 
dDebug Source Loaction: 
dSymbol file: 
dDumper libraries:  C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\\qtc-debugging-helper\ C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\qtc-debugging-helper\168937759\ C:\Users\encore\AppData\Local\Nokia\QtCreator\qtc-debugging-helper\168937759\
d
dDebugger settings: 
dUseAlternatingRowColours: false  (default: false)
dFontSizeFollowsEditor: false  (default: false)
dUseMessageBoxForSignals: true  (default: true)
dAutoQuit: false  (default: false)
dLogTimeStamps: false  (default: false)
dVerboseLog: false  (default: false)
dCloseBuffersOnExit: false  (default: false)
dSwitchModeOnExit: false  (default: false)
dUseDebuggingHelper: true  (default: true)
dUseCodeModel: true  (default: true)
dShowThreadNames: false  (default: false)
dUseToolTips: false  (default: false)
dUseToolTipsInLocalsView: false  (default: false)
dUseToolTipsInBreakpointsView: false  (default: false)
dUseAddressInBreakpointsView: false  (default: false)
dUseAddressInStackView: false  (default: false)
dRegisterForPostMortem: false  (default: false)
dLoadGdbInit: true  (default: true)
dScriptFile:   (default: )
dWatchdogTimeout: 20  (default: 20)
dAutoEnrichParameters: false  (default: false)
dTargetAsync: false  (default: false)
dMaximalStackDepth: 20  (default: 20)
dAlwaysAdjustStackColumnWidths: false  (default: false)
dShowStandardNamespace: true  (default: true)
dShowQtNamespace: true  (default: true)
dSortStructMembers: true  (default: true)
dAutoDerefPointers: true  (default: true)
dAlwaysAdjustLocalsColumnWidths: false  (default: false)
dListSourceFiles: false  (default: false)
dSkipKnownFrames: false  (default: false)
dEnableReverseDebugging: false  (default: false)
dAllPluginBreakpoints: true  (default: true)
dSelectedPluginBreakpoints: false  (default: false)
dAdjustBreakpointLocations: true  (default: true)
dAlwaysAdjustBreakpointsColumnWidths: false  (default: false)
dNoPluginBreakpoints: false  (default: false)
dSelectedPluginBreakpointsPattern: .*  (default: .*)
dBreakOnThrow: false  (default: false)
dBreakOnCatch: false  (default: false)
dBreakOnWarning: false  (default: false)
dBreakOnFatal: false  (default: false)
dAlwaysAdjustRegistersColumnWidths: false  (default: false)
dAlwaysAdjustSnapshotsColumnWidths: false  (default: false)
dAlwaysAdjustThreadsColumnWidths: false  (default: false)
dAlwaysAdjustModulesColumnWidths: false  (default: false)
dState changed from DebuggerNotReady(0) to EngineSetupRequested(1).
dQUEUE: SETUP ENGINE
dCALL: SETUP ENGINE
dTRYING TO START ADAPTER
dENABLING TEST CASE: 0
dSTARTING C:/QtSDK/pythongdb/python_2.7based/gdb-i686-pc-mingw32.exe -i mi
dGDB STARTED, INITIALIZING IT
<1show version
<2-list-features
<3set print object on
<4set breakpoint pending on
<5set print elements 10000
<6set overload-resolution off
<7handle SIGSEGV nopass stop print
<8set unwindonsignal on
<9pwd
<10set width 0
<11set height 0
<12set auto-solib-add on
<13-interpreter-exec console "maintenance set internal-warning quit no"
<14-interpreter-exec console "maintenance set internal-error quit no"
<15-interpreter-exec console "disassemble 0 0"
<16-interpreter-exec console "python execfile('C:/QtSDK/QtCreator/share/qtcreator/dumper/bridge.py')"
<17-interpreter-exec console "python execfile('C:/QtSDK/QtCreator/share/qtcreator/dumper/dumper.py')"
<18-interpreter-exec console "python execfile('C:/QtSDK/QtCreator/share/qtcreator/dumper/qttypes.py')"
<19-interpreter-exec console "bbsetup"
dADAPTER SUCCESSFULLY STARTED
dNOTE: ENGINE SETUP OK
dState changed from EngineSetupRequested(1) to EngineSetupOk(3).
dQUEUE: SETUP INFERIOR
dState changed from EngineSetupOk(3) to InferiorSetupRequested(4).
dQUEUE: SETUP INFERIOR
dCALL: SETUP INFERIOR
sSetting up inferior...
<20set substitute-path C:/iwmake/build_mingw_opensource C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/mingw
<21set substitute-path C:/ndk_buildrepos/qt-desktop/src C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/mingw
<22set substitute-path C:/qt-greenhouse/Trolltech/Code_less_create_more/Trolltech/Code_less_create_more/Troll/4.6/qt C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/mingw
 Attaching to 1260 (6412)
dTaking notice of pid 1260
<23attach 1260
>=thread-group-added,id="i1"
>~"GNU gdb (GDB) 7.2\n"
>~"Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.\n"
>~"License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>\nThis is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.\nThere is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type \"show copying\"\nand \"show warranty\" for details.\n"
>~"This GDB was configured as \"i686-pc-mingw32\".\nFor bug reporting instructions, please see:\n"
>~"<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.\n"
>&"show version\n"
>~"GNU gdb (GDB) 7.2\n"
>~"Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.\n"
>~"License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>\nThis is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.\nThere is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type \"show copying\"\nand \"show warranty\" for details.\n"
>~"This GDB was configured as \"i686-pc-mingw32\".\nFor bug reporting instructions, please see:\n"
>~"<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.\n"
>1^done
dPARSING VERSION: 1^done
d
dSUPPORTED GDB VERSION GNU gdb (GDB) 7.2
dCopyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
dLicense GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
dThis is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
dThere is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
dand "show warranty" for details.
dThis GDB was configured as "i686-pc-mingw32".
dFor bug reporting instructions, please see:
d<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
dGNU gdb (GDB) 7.2
dCopyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
dLicense GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
dThis is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
dThere is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
dand "show warranty" for details.
dThis GDB was configured as "i686-pc-mingw32".
dFor bug reporting instructions, please see:
d<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
d
dUSING GDB VERSION: 70200, BUILD: 2010
>2^done,features=["frozen-varobjs","pending-breakpoints","thread-info","python"]
dFEATURES: 2^done,data={features=["frozen-varobjs","pending-breakpoints","thread-info","python"]}
d
>&"set print object on\n"
>3^done
>&"set breakpoint pending on\n"
>4^done
>&"set print elements 10000\n"
>5^done
>&"set overload-resolution off\n"
>6^done
>&"handle SIGSEGV nopass stop print\n"
>~"Signal        Stop\tPrint\tPass to program\tDescription\n"
>~"SIGSEGV       Yes\tYes\tNo\t\tSegmentation fault\n"
>7^done
>&"set unwindonsignal on\n"
>8^done
>&"pwd\n"
>~"Working directory C:\\Users\\encore.\n"
>9^done
>&"set width 0\n"
>10^done
>&"set height 0\n"
>11^done
>&"set auto-solib-add on\n"
>12^done
>13^done
>14^done
>&"A syntax error in expression, near `0'.\n"
>15^error,msg="A syntax error in expression, near `0'."
>16^done
>17^done
>18^done
>~"dumpers=[{type=\"QLinkedList\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QSize\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QFileInfo\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QAbstractItemModel\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"std__stack\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QTextDocument\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QTJSC__JSValue\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"__gnu_cxx__hash_set\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QStringList\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QRegion\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"std__wstring\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QString\",formats=\"Inline,Separate Window\",editable=\"true\"},{type=\"QTextCodec\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QBasicAtomicInt\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QScriptValue\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QTime\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QSharedData\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"std__vector\",formats=\"\",editable=\"true\"},{type=\"QRegExp\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QTextCursor\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QxXmlAttributes\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QDateTime\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QList\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QStandardItem\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"std__deque\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QFixed\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QHash\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QSharedPointer\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QUrl\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"std__set\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"std__list\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"std__basic_string\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QPoint\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QHostAddress\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QStack\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QScopedPointer\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QRectF\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QMultiMap\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QMapNode\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QModelIndex\",formats=\"Normal,Enhanced\"},{type=\"QLocale\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QSharedDataPointer\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QVariant\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"string\",formats=\"\",editable=\"true\"},{type=\"QBasicAtomicPointer\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QVector\",formats=\"\",editable=\"true\"},{type=\"QDate\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QFile\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QAtomicInt\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"TBuf\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QWeakPointer\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QSizeF\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"__m128\",formats=\"As Floats,As Doubles\"},{type=\"boost__optional\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"wstring\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QPointF\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"TLitC\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QRect\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QByteArray\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QMap\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"boost__shared_ptr\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QChar\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QDir\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QPixmap\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QFlags\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"std__map\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QHashNode\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QTemporaryFile\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"QObject\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"Eigen__Matrix\",formats=\"\"},{type=\"std__string\",formats=\"\",editable=\"true\"},{type=\"QImage\",formats=\"Normal,Displayed\"},{type=\"QSet\",formats=\"\"},],hasInferiorThreadList=\"1\"\n"
>19^done
>&"set substitute-path C:/iwmake/build_mingw_opensource C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/mingw\n"
>20^done
>&"set substitute-path C:/ndk_buildrepos/qt-desktop/src C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/mingw\n"
>21^done
>&"set substitute-path C:/qt-greenhouse/Trolltech/Code_less_create_more/Trolltech/Code_less_create_more/Troll/4.6/qt C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/mingw\n"
>22^done
>&"attach 1260\n"
>~"Attaching to process 1260\n"
>=thread-group-started,id="i1",pid="1260"
sThread group i1 created
>=thread-created,id="1",group-id="i1"
sThread 1 created
>~"[New Thread 1260.0x190c]\n"
s[New Thread 1260.0x190c]
>23^running
 Inferior attached, thread 6412 resumed
sSetting breakpoints...
dSetting breakpoints...
<24maint print msymbols C:/Users/encore/AppData/Local/Temp/gdb_ns_.Dq6408
>*running,thread-id="all"
>=thread-created,id="2",group-id="i1"
sThread 2 created
>~"[New Thread 1260.0xf9c]\n"
s[New Thread 1260.0xf9c]
>*running,thread-id="all"
>=thread-exited,id="2",group-id="i1"
sThread 2 in group i1 exited
>=thread-exited,id="1",group-id="i1"
sThread 1 in group i1 exited
>=thread-group-exited,id="i1"
sThread group i1 exited
>&"During startup program exited with code 0xc0000138.\n"
>23^error,msg="During startup program exited with code 0xc0000138."
dCOOKIE FOR TOKEN 23 ALREADY EATEN (InferiorSetupRequested). TWO RESPONSES FOR ONE COMMAND?
dNOTE: INFERIOR EXITED
dState changed from InferiorSetupRequested(4) to InferiorExitOk(16).
dState changed from InferiorExitOk(16) to InferiorShutdownOk(19).
dState changed from InferiorShutdownOk(19) to EngineShutdownRequested(20).
dQUEUE: SHUTDOWN ENGINE
sExecutable failed: During startup program exited with code 0xc0000138.
dCALL: SHUTDOWN ENGINE
dINITIATE GDBENGINE SHUTDOWN IN STATE 0, PROC: 2
<25-gdb-exit
>&"maint print msymbols C:/Users/encore/AppData/Local/Temp/gdb_ns_.Dq6408\n"
>24^done
dFOUND NON-NAMESPACED QT
dNOTE: INFERIOR SETUP OK
dState changed from EngineShutdownRequested(20) to InferiorSetupOk(6).
dState changed from InferiorSetupOk(6) to EngineRunRequested(7).
dQUEUE: RUN ENGINE
dCALL: RUN ENGINE
dNOTE: ENGINE RUN AND INFERIOR STOP OK
dState changed from EngineRunRequested(7) to InferiorStopOk(14).
dNOTE: INFERIOR RUN REQUESTED
dState changed from InferiorStopOk(14) to InferiorRunRequested(10).
sRunning requested...
<26-exec-continue
>25^exit
dGDB CLAIMS EXIT; WAITING
dGDB PROCESS FINISHED, status 0, code 0
dNOTE: ENGINE ILL ******
dState changed BY FORCE from InferiorRunRequested(10) to InferiorStopRequested(13).
dATTEMPT TO INTERRUPT INFERIOR
sStop requested...
dTRYING TO INTERRUPT INFERIOR
dCANNOT INTERRUPT 1260
```

do you have any idea as to how I can handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exit code 0xc0000138 is `STATUS_ORDINAL_NOT_FOUND` (I checked it by `perl -MWin32::Status -E 'say $Win32::Status::INTEGER_TO_SYMBOL{ 0xc0000138 }'`, it can also be found in the ntstatus.h header, e.g. http://source.winehq.org/source/include/ntstatus.h)

An "ordinal not found" error means that some function provided by a DLL couldn't be found; possibly the wrong version of the DLL was loaded.  I'm not sure if the same error can be produced when a DLL is entirely missing.

Can you verify the following?

- OpenCV DLL(s) exist
- OpenCV DLL(s) are in PATH
- OpenCV DLL(s) match the version of your `<opencv/*>` headers
- OpenCV libs are listed in your .pro file; there should be some `LIBS+=...` statements relating to OpenCV.  There's an example of what it might look like here - http://mobidevelopers.wordpress.com/2009/01/29/qt-and-opencv/

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I just reinstalled everything. It seems some files were colliding with another installation I'd done in the past ;)