# CMake + qtcreator + MinGW + Debug mode + Windows 7

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, mingw, qt-creator

I use `CMake` with `VC++` under windows 7 and everything works fine. Now, I want to test `qtcreator` but I cannot force debug flags. I am using `MinGW` generator with cmake and adding `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` on the command line.

I can use CMake feature from inside QTCreator to generate projects with `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`. It compiles just fine and I can run it. However, I cannot debug it as QTCreator complains it is not a "debuggable executale". I also tried generating the projects directly using the command line.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Are you trying to compile a Qt based code or only a C++ code without Qt classes?

Comment: @QtBlueWaffle: C++11 code without Qt classes. I need to use MinGW that's why I need QTCreator.

Comment: Well I don't understand why you need Qt Creator to compile a c++ code with mingw. can't you use directly g++? http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MinGWforFirstTimeUsers . Qt Creator is dedicated to Qt based code + UI designing OMHO

Comment: Because I need to edit it afterwards and I also want to test QTCreator.

Comment: Please start CMake in verbose mode and check the output. Maybe somethink went wront which is not visible.

Comment: How did you determine that the debug flags were not set? Are you sure you should not be using the CodeBlocks generator, in order to generate project files understandable by QtCreator?

Comment: QTCreator integrates CMake so it should work. I just believe that there is no debug flags generated (or at least none in QTcreator) because QTCreator says so;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you did nothing wrong.

When using MSVC in Debug mode, debug symbols (*.pdb files) are generated in the same folder than your built binary. They can be used later to debug you application.

When using MingW, no additional file is generated. When you configure a CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to `Debug` or `RelWithDebInfo`, the option `-g` is added to the compilation command line. This produce debug information inside the binary. Then, you will be able to debug your program with GDB (you can try it in Qt Creator, it works ;))

You can verify this by changing CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE values and check the size of your resulting binary. I just test for one of my projects:

```
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE                      Executable size
<empty>                                   1890 Ko
Release                                   1281 Ko
Debug                                    14743 Ko
MinSizeRel                                1027 Ko
RelWithDebInfo                           15859 Ko
```

Comment: So you mean you are able to generate a MinGW project with CMake, then compile it with QTcreator and debug inside QTCreator? Can you provide the detailed steps to do so starting from CMake please?

Comment: You must ensure your MingW compiler is registered in QtCreator options and verify you have a Kit configured with this compiler (Name your kit MingW 4.8 for example). In QC, file > open file or project, select the CMakeLists.txt on your disk. Click on Next, select your kit ("Generator") then "Run CMake". Your project should be configured in Qt Creator.

Comment: A good additional step by step can be found on http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-project-cmake.html

Comment: I am already compiling my project from CMake to QTcreator for final app with MinGW. But, QTCreator will not let me debug my app saying that this is not a debug version of my executable. So once again, if you have a CMakeLists.txt file that you can use in QTCreator to generate a "MinGW project", compile it and debug it, it would be great to detail your steps in your answer. Thanks.

Comment: And if you detail a bit more the steps you followed to try to compile your project, it could be useful for us to answer you. I detailed step by step how to open a CMake project in QT Creator. I also answer to your question: MingW compiler produces debugging symbols directly in the binary. So if you don't succeed to debug your program, you have missed something. Don't be condescending with people trying to help you. Do a tiny effort on your side to explain what exactly you did, and somebedy will probably help you...

Comment: Your question is 3 lines long and you want a step by step tutorial to find your error ? Please read your question : "What am I doing wrong?" How can we tell you what you did wrong if you don't explain what you did ?

Comment: If you read my comments, you can easily see what I already did. I can copy paste it in the question if it helps you though. Also, do you actually HAVE a working example of a CMakeLists.txt file you can open from QTCreator to compile with MinGW and then debug it?

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded ZIP files (main + Logger + o2), generated project opening the CMakeLists.txt file from inside QTCreator and build the project but it does not link. At least with both MinGW and VS2012 Kits.  I will try to manually generate VS2012 project files and see what's going on.

Comment: warning: 'Logger::Logger()' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored [-Wattributes]
 Logger::Logger() and a lot of others. CUTELOGGER_LIBRARY is not defined. Would it be because I download ZIP archives instead of doing git clone? Should not.
 ^

Comment: I build CuteLogger statically in my code, and the CMakeList delivered with CuteLogger is not used. Everything is done from the libs/CMakeLists.txt file. Additionally, git submodules allows to have a specific revision for each library. I didn't try since some month to update both libraries to last versions.

Comment: Thanks for the video. The only difference between what you did and what I did is that I was not using GDB. I changed that and now it launchs ok but GDB complains about "unexpected exit". I think I will have to double check your video and lastly check my installation.

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905300/qt-unexpected-gdb-exit you can find someone having exactly the same error message, and providing all logs he has. From that another people find in the log the exit code and helps the first guy to determine what exactly is wrong with its environment

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41808/discussion-between-antoine-lorence-and-korchkidu)

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to figure out what's wrong so I'll give you a few hints:

1. Set `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE` in CMakeChace.txt file and run `cmake` again. Then call `make clean` and `make`. Then examine output and check what flags are being passed to compiler.
2. Check CMakeCache.txt file for flags which are passed to compiler for particular builds. Check if -g and -O0 are passed for debug mode.
3. Try to build a very simple program and compile it manually with -g and -O0. Then try to debug it with gdb and QtCreator (as external application) and check if that's a problem with QtCreator itself or your compiler options.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hints. I will try to see what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

I run into this problem today just like you. Most likely you are using VS CDB instead of GDB.

Here is my solution:

(0) download MinGW and GCC from http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/index.php

(1) set environment variable, so Qt-creator can auto detect MinGW and GCC

set MINGW_DIR
add %MINGW_DIR% to PATH

(2) re-start Qt-creator

open Qt-creator -> tools->options->Build&Run->kits

add manually "MinGW-GCC" (or other name you like)

check compiler, gcc should be auto detected

set Debugger ->Edit : GDB Engine and choose the folder of gdb.exe

Make sure that CDB is not used

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with QtCreator, but I'll try to help by explaining what I used to generate makefiles for Eclipse CDT4 (which may be another option for you to try as a Windows IDE).

First, are you sure your cmake can generate QtCreator makefiles? I ask because at least on Fedora, cmake doesn't list Qtcreator as an option.

Typing "cmake" on the command line should list the generators available for your platform. Is QtCreator one of them?

Second, it is quite possible that cmake just doesn't have that option for your compiler. This does not necessarily mean that you won't be able to debug code from that compiler. For example, I generated files for Eclipse CDT without setting the debug flags, but am still able to debug just fine.

For reference, here is the list of commands I used for Eclipse CDT (from the project root dir, the cmakelists.txt file is in the src subdirectory):

```
mkdir eclipse-project
cd eclipse-project
cmake ../src -G "Eclipse CDT - Unix Makefiles"
```

Then I can open the project from Eclipse and debug. I suspect you'll be able to do the same, whether cmake knows how to enable debug for your compiler or not.

Comment: Qt Creator has its own interface to run CMake. There is no QtCreator generator in CMake. To open a CMake project in QtCreator, everything is done in QtCreator.